# Why is permission denied on pip install except for when "--user" is included at end of command?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, installation

I use pip install to install various python packages on my Mac OS terminal. If I don't include "--user" at the end, I am consistently notified that there was an "EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied". However, if I include --user at the end, I am able to install packages. However, on other Apple computers I use the Terminal and Python for, I have no trouble installing packages and I do not need to add "--user" to the end.

Why the difference here? Why do I need to include --user to the end of my pip install commands for one Mac laptop but not for others?

Comment: Your Python version is probably installed in a directory only the root user can access. the `--user` flag prompts it to install packages in your user directories (and, by that, only for the current user) rather than the in it's installation directory. running it as root should resolve this, but there's nothing "wrong" with using `--user`.

Comment: Apple’s pre-installed Python requires `sudo pip`. But you rarely want to use Apple’s pre-installed Python on current macOS. Even if you want 2.7 rather than a newer Python, you probably want to install it with Homebrew, a Python.org installer, or Anaconda/Miniconda, and none of them require sudo if you use the default installation settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With a virtual environment activated, `pip install spam` tries to install into the virtual environment's site-packages. This will almost always be somewhere you have write permissions for.
- `pip install --user spam` tries to install into the user-packages directory. This will always be somewhere under your home directory, so you should always have write permissions for it.
- `pip install spam` tries to install files into the site-packages directory for your Python installation. This will usually not be in your home directory (typically it's somewhere in `/Library`), so you may or may not have write permissions.

  - Apple's pre-installed Python *does not* give you write permissions to its site-packages.

    - `sudo pip install spam` will let you ignore the permissions by installing as root, although with some Python installations it may cause other problems.
  - Homebrew, Python.org, and Anaconda/Miniconda *do* give you write permissions to their site-packages if you leave the defaults alone.

    - Obviously, leave the defaults alone if you know what you're doing.
  - Less common ways of installing (Enthought, building from source, MacPorts, etc.), you should read the appropriate docs.

So, most likely, you're using a third-party Python and/or an active virtual environment on the machines where `pip install spam` works, but you're using Apple's pre-installed Python on the ones where it doesn't.

While you *could* fix that by using `sudo`, you probably don't want to, for a few reasons:

- On recent versions of macOS, Apple's pre-installed Python, and the packages they pre-install with it, are badly out of date.
- The pre-installed packages are set up to be maintained with the deprecated `easy_install` rather than `pip`, so getting them up to date can be a huge pain.
- If you mess things up too badly, you can break some system scripts that the OS depends on.
- Your changes can be undone by a macOS system update.

So, a better solution is to install Homebrew/Anaconda/Python.org Python if you can, and also use virtual environments when you can and `--user` whenever possible when you can't. Any one of these three will solve your problem, but you really should do all of them.

And then, if you accidentally try to install something to Apple's site-packages, you'll get a permissions error—but that's a good thing; it means you didn't actually change anything, so you have nothing to undo.